# D3D9 circle primitive bug

Tags: directx, primitive, ellipse, direct3d9

I tried to draw a 2D circle with D3D9 per vertices and DrawPrimitive but failed somehow.

The white points in the picture below representing my vertices and the cyan circle is rendered with my function.

[image: Click here for example image]

This is my ellipse function

```
RETURN CRender::Ellipse( SPos Position, SSize Size, int Sides, int LineWidth, CColor* BgColor, CColor* LineColor, float Abundance )
{
    // check if parameters valid
    if( !BgColor || !LineColor ) return R_FAILED; // check pointers
    if( Abundance > 1 || Abundance < 0 ) (Abundance > 1) ? Abundance = 1 : Abundance = 0; // max. & min. abundance

    // instance needed vars
    int VertexSize = ( Sides * Abundance ); // how much vertices to draw ?
    int abSize = VertexSize * sizeof( CUSTOMVERTEX ); // absolute size in byte
    double PosOffset = 0; // used in function below
    LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 VertexBuffer = NULL; // instance vertex buffer
    CUSTOMVERTEX* Vertex = new CUSTOMVERTEX[ VertexSize ]; // instance vertices
    D3DXVECTOR2* Line = new D3DXVECTOR2[ VertexSize ]; // instance outline
    VOID* pData = NULL; // pipe data

    // calc vertices
    Vertex[ 0 ] = FillVertex( Position.X, Position.Y, /*Position.Z*/ 0, 1, BgColor->ToDWORD() );
    for( int i = 1; i <= VertexSize; i++, PosOffset += (2*PI) / Sides )
    {
        // corrections
        while( PosOffset > 2*PI ) PosOffset -= 2*PI;
        // instance vertex
        Vertex[ i ] = FillVertex(    ( cos(PosOffset) * Size.Width ) + Position.X,
                                    ( sin(PosOffset) * Size.Height ) + Position.Y,
                                    /*( tan(PosOffset) * Size.Depth ) + Position.Z*/ 0, // fix 2D position
                                    1, BgColor->ToDWORD() );
    }

    // instance buffer
    Device->CreateVertexBuffer( abSize, D3DUSAGE_WRITEONLY, CUSTOMFVF, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, &VertexBuffer, NULL );

    // prepare buffer
    VertexBuffer->Lock( NULL, abSize, (void**)&pData, NULL );
    memcpy( pData, Vertex, abSize );
    VertexBuffer->Unlock( );

    // prepare primitive
    Device->SetRenderState( D3DRS_ZENABLE, D3DZB_FALSE );
    Device->SetRenderState( D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, true );
    Device->SetRenderState( D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA );
    Device->SetRenderState( D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_INVSRCALPHA );

    // draw primitive
    Device->SetStreamSource( 0, VertexBuffer, NULL, sizeof( CUSTOMVERTEX ) );
    Device->DrawPrimitive( D3DPT_TRIANGLEFAN, 0, VertexSize - 2 );

    return R_OK;
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, obviously the last 2 vertices won't be drawn.
Would be very glad if somebody could explain to me whats wrong!

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behavior of geometry type D3DPT_TRIANGLEFAN, suppose you want to split the ellipse to 4 sides, you will need 5 vertex(plus the center of the ellipse v0) as below, so you will get 5 - 2 = 3 triangle fans, that's v0v1v2, v0v2v3, and v0v3v4, but you won't get v0v4v1, Direct3D won't do that for you.

[image]

if you want to get the last triangle fan v0v4v1, you need an extra vertex to store v1, something like

```
vextex[5] = vertex[1]
```

now you have 6 vertex, so you will get 6 - 2 = 4 triangle fans including v0v4v1.

you need two extra vertex, one for the center of the ellipse, one for the last vertex

```
int VertexSize = ( Sides * Abundance ) + 2;
```

Add this line below the for loop, this will add the last vertex in order to draw the last triangle fan.

```
Vertex[VertexSize -1] = Vertex[1];
```

[Triangle fans in Direct3D 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)